# Best way to implement a recycled cells grid in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

While we are still waiting for CollectionView at 4.0, what would be the best memory-safe way to implement a huge list of several columns with complex cells (images and text combined), using Xamarin.Forms?

[image]

Comment: You can try the preview of `CollectionView` which [can be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) in XF 3.6. Otherwise, if you want recycling the best bet right now is to find a way to use a `ListView`, which I get is not ideal with your layout.

Comment: They don't have it implemented for all platforms. The closest i found was FastGrid from https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib

Comment: Did you try by set `CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElement` on your `ListView` ? also you could try this library [FlowListView](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView)

Comment: FlowListView might be a good answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally ended up implementing my own solution:

https://github.com/taublast/MultiColumnsListView

[image]